# Is there a way to make bash recognize aliases with prefixes

Tags: bash, alias

Assume you defined the alias `alias grep='grep --color=auto'` in `~/.bashrc`. Then invoking `sudo grep` wouldn't trigger the alias to be used. Is there a way to do so? If yes, would that solution be applicable to a piped command as well (e.g `cat file | grep 'a'`)?

I'm using `bash` 4.3.30 on Ubuntu 14.10.